# When should I use getActivity() and getContext() from a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-context

I was wondering when should I use getActivity() and getContext() from a Fragment? and why not using getActivity always. Is there any situation where getActivity could fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure there is a `getActivityContext()` method, but as far as the difference between `getContext()` and `getActivity()`, there really isn't one other than the type you get back from the call.  From the source the v4 Fragment, it's just a convenience method that casts the `Context` to an `Activity` or `FragmentActivity` before returning, and it's similar for the normal `Fragment` class.

```
/**
 * Return the {@link Context} this fragment is currently associated with.
 */
public Context getContext() {
    return mHost == null ? null : mHost.getContext();
}

/**
 * Return the {@link FragmentActivity} this fragment is currently associated with.
 * May return {@code null} if the fragment is associated with a {@link Context}
 * instead.
 */
final public FragmentActivity getActivity() {
    return mHost == null ? null : (FragmentActivity) mHost.getActivity();
}
```

Also, an Activity is a Context, so there's not much of a difference.

Comment: I think OP was talking about `Activity#getApplicationContext()` - in which case there is actually a decent difference. Use `#getApplicationContext()` if you want a `Context` that is tied to the entire application's lifecycle, or use `#getActivity()` if you want a `Context` that is tied to the activity's life cycle. Subtle difference, but can have a huge impact depending on OP's needs.